# How to change the language of error messages in Integration Services Project

Tags: ssis

I'm running a data tools of Integration Services project. I get the errors in german and I would like to get them in english. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In SSDT, try going to **Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings** and making sure English is the language selected there.